# beginner in c++ and i face this problem error C3867

Tags: c++

this my first c++ project by using classes and i face this problem
error C3867

my `main` code is

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Car.h"
int main() {
  Car c1;
  c1.setMaker("Honda");
  c1.setModel(2018);
  cout << "This Car Made By" << c1.getMaker << "\n";
  cout << "This Car Model" << c1.getModel << "\n";
}
```

the header is

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Car {
 private:
  string maker;
  int model;

 public:
  void setMaker(string m);
  string getMaker();
  void setModel(int m);
  int getModel();
```

the cpp is

```
#include "Car.h"

void Car::setMaker(string l) { maker = l; }

string Car::getMaker() { return maker; }

void Car::setModel(int m) { model = m; }

int Car::getModel() { return model; }
```

and this is the error message:
`error C3867:  'Car::getMaker': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

i've tried everything i know as a beginner but i can't make it work :(

Comment: `c1.getMaker` that's not how you call a function. Add `()` to the end. Calling functions is a rather basic language feature, I suggest using a good book or tutorial to learn the language.

Comment: @Blaze Such comments are best accompanied with a link to our [list of good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Comment: Admittedly the error message might appear somewhat puzzling to a beginner. Change `c1.getMaker` to `c1.getMaker()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call functions with a parameter list at the end, even if that list is empty.

E.g

`c1.getMaker` is the address to the getMaker function

`c1.getMaker()` actually calls the function

Comment: thank you it`s working now :* ^_^